# How to take a screen shot of Project Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to take a screen shot of my **Project Explorer** so that I can post it as part of a question I have about my project's **Build Path**.

I have tried **Window >> Show View >> Devices** .. but that's for a screen shot of my device. I tried **Show View >> Pixel Perfect** which **saves the screenshot as a PNG**, but then I couldn't find where it gets saved, and also how to frame it on to my **Project Explorer**. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use the regular printscreen key, take the picture and crop it to take only the part you want?

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan  You are right and Pixel Perfect is  only for the device screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just take a Windows screenshot with the Print Screen key, and you can use the paint to edit the size or highlight what you want and add comments.

Also there are several external applications that will help you to do this kind of screenshots

http://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Microsoft-Windows

http://lifehacker.com/5880928/the-best-screen-capture-tool-for-windows

Comment: That's great, Windows screenshot normally goes on clipboard and Windows 8 can put it straight into a file in Screenshots Folder in My Pictures, thanks!